Fatal Firmware Error on Raspberry Pi 5 (4GB) After Recovery Attempt
I’m experiencing a “Fatal Firmware Error” on my Raspberry Pi 5 (4GB model), indicated by a specific LED flash pattern (four slow green flashes followed by five fast flashes). Here’s the situation:

The Pi was working fine a few days ago with no hardware accidents or physical damage.
I attempted to flash a new OS, and the board started showing the “Fatal Firmware Error” LED pattern.

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Flashed a fresh OS (Raspberry Pi OS) onto the SD card.
Attempted EEPROM Recovery using the official Raspberry Pi EEPROM recovery image:

The Pi displayed the green screen, indicating the recovery was initiated.
After waiting for a few minutes, the screen went black, and I powered off the Pi.


After recovery, I tried booting without the SD card, but the fatal firmware error pattern appeared again.
I used the official Raspberry Pi 5 power supply (5V 3A) and tested with minimal setup (no peripherals, just power and HDMI).
Tried booting with and without the SD card multiple times after recovery, but the same issue persists.

Additional Information:

Firmware Recovery seems to start correctly (green screen appears), but the Pi still fails to boot after recovery.
No solid green LED occurs when I try booting now, only the error LED pattern.

My Questions:

Is there any way to fully re-flash the bootloader/EEPROM firmware beyond the recovery process I’ve tried?
Could this issue still be software-related, or does it point to a hardware defect at the bootloader/firmware level?
Are there any further troubleshooting steps I can try before considering a hardware replacement?

My Setup:

Raspberry Pi 5 (4GB)
Official Raspberry Pi 5 power supply
OS: Raspberry Pi OS (tried both 32-bit and 64-bit)
HDMI connected to monitor


I attempted to flash a new OS - can you expand on this. Which OS? where did you get it? How did you flash it?

I am using the very basic raspberry and OS 64 bits that recommended one I tried the one from raspberry pi imager installed on my Mac but when it failed, I tried the one from the raspberry pi website directly
